# leading slash in namespace

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm studying hard about ROS and gazebo.

Now I'm very confused about namespace.

Is there any difference in between `/p3dx/base_link` and `p3dx/base_link`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212356/leading-slash-in-namespace/) by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/Names

> Names that start with a "/" are global -- they are considered fully resolved. Global names should be avoided as much as possible as they limit code portability.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2